# How to map an NHibernate entity to a query

Tags: sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbm

I've seen a number of examples of this, and as far as I can tell my HBM file follows the same pattern, but it's not working.  First, the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="save-update" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="ThinAir" mutable="false" lazy="true" >
    <id name="JobId">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="UserLogin"/>
    <property name="UserEmail"/>
    <property name="DateProcessed"/>
    <loader query-ref="myquery"/>
  </class>
  <sql-query name="myquery">
    <return class="ThinAir">
      <return-property name="JobID" column="JobId"/>
      <return-property name="userLogin" column="UserLogin"/>
      <return-property name="DateProcessed" column="DateProcessed"/>
      <return-property name="userEmail" column="UserEmail"/>
    </return>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT DISTINCT JobID,
    userLogin,
    DateProcessed,
    useremail
    FROM         dbo.someothertable
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

"myquery" in-and-of-itself, works.  That is to say, if I call

```
var x = session.GetNamedQuery("myquery").List();
```

I get a correct List of **ThinAir** objects.

But, when I try to get a list of **ThinAirs** like this:

```
var submissions = session.CreateCriteria<ThinAir>().List<ThinAir>();
```

I get

> Test method testThinAir threw exception: 
>   NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
>       [ SELECT this_.JobId as JobId16_0_, this_.UserLogin as UserLogin16_0_, this_.UserEmail as UserEmail16_0_, this_.DateProcessed as DateProc4_16_0_ FROM **ThinAir** this_ ]

My interpretation of this phenomenon is that NH is ignoring my `<loader>` tag and so trying to load the data from the underlying table, which by default it assumes to be named **ThinAir** because that's the name of the entity class, only there *isn't* any **ThinAir** table, hence the error message.

Is that interpretation correct?  And in any case, what am I doing wrong and how can I do it right?

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way how to achieve this, would be to move the mapping from a *query* into the `subselect`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="save-update" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="ThinAir" mutable="false" lazy="true" >

  <subselect>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT DISTINCT JobID,
    userLogin,
    DateProcessed,
    useremail
    FROM         dbo.someothertable
    ]]>
  </subselect>

  ... // rest of the mapping
```

Comment: Thank you very much:  That works like a charm, though I still don't understand why my original method didn't...  Where the heck is this stuff documented?

Comment: Great if that helped. Yes, documentation could be a bit better. But these anyhow, NHiberante does amazing stuff... which could be partially hard to find ;) good luck