# How to use subquery as a join in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, hibernate, nhibernate

I have the following SQL code:

```
SELECT err.*,tmp.counted FROM sm_database.error err
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sme_Hash, COUNT(*) as counted FROM sm_database.error GROUP BY sme_Hash
) tmp
ON tmp.sme_Hash = err.sme_Hash
WHERE sme_Id = 197
```

Above will get me a extra column counted that should set into my Count property below.

the id 197 will be parameter I will use in a method.

My class name is:

```
public class Error {

    public virtual int Count { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Hash { get; set; } 

    -----------------
    //more property's 

}
```

I want to "convert" this into NHibernate with Query(or QueryOver)

Anyone know how to do this properly or could point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

I got it with the following:

```
 string query = @"SELECT err.* ,tmp.Count 
                      FROM sm_database.error err 
                      LEFT JOIN ( 
                      SELECT sme_Hash as Hash, COUNT(*) as Count FROM sm_database.error GROUP BY sme_Hash
                      ) tmp
                      ON tmp.Hash = err.sme_Hash
                      WHERE sme_Id = :id";

        var result = session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
                   .AddEntity(typeof(Error))

                  .SetParameter("id", id).List<Error>().SingleOrDefault();
```

It works fine, everthing is pulled except the Count property.

The Count property in my Error class isn't mapped cause we don't have a column in the database because we calculated the count in the query.

Is there a way to get the tmp.Count value in my Error.Count property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy answer, no built in solution for this kind of SQL construct.

The options how to go around are:

1) Create special entity and map it to this view: `"SELECT sme_Hash, COUNT(*) as counted FROM sm_database.error GROUP BY sme_Hash"` It could be either DB view or mapping with subselect (see [Mapping native sql to Entity with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33487498/1679310))

2) use native SQL with CreateSQLQuery

Because NHibernate provides querying on top of Entity model. I.e. the FROM is always coming from mapping. No way how to create that as above